# Random number generator is giving zero still when minimum and maximum is given

Tags: javascript

```
var prevRandomNum = -1;
var arr=[];
var math=[];

window.onload=function(){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("manga");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    arr.push(childKey);

});

  }); 
}
function g(){
     const btn = document.getElementById("btng");
    btn.innerText = "Suggest me another";
    var sorry="im/sorry.png";
console.log(arr.length);
    var randomNum;
   var calc=arr.length-1;
if(math.length==calc){
            document.getElementById("mname").textContent= "Sorry you have reached the end of the manga list i have suggested.";
         document.getElementById("mgenre").textContent= "I will be uploading new suggestions soon.";
         document.getElementById("mchap").textContent= "";
         document.getElementById("mstatus").textContent= "";
            document.getElementById("img").src=sorry;
         document.getElementById("pic").style.backgroundImage=`url(${sorry})`;
        
        }
        else{
           do{ 
        randomNum= Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length-1) )+1;
        
    
       console.log("rand "+ randomNum);
        
        
        }while(randomNum=== prevRandomNum||math.includes(randomNum));
        
    
    prevRandomNum = randomNum;
math.push(prevRandomNum);
}
```

Above is the code I am using to retrieve data from firebase database and get value of a specific parent node using random number, i have stored push key in array and i am using random number generator to get a unique and random parent data every time when the button is pressed but the random is giving out 0 as random number even while minimum and maximum number is given. You can check live preview here https://kazemanga.xyz/ please open the console to see if the random number is zero or not. Any help would be appreciated.

**arr.length=7 (the no of parent node on db is 7)**
It may not give random no as Zero on first click so plz refresh and try again, it doesn't give zero sometimes and when I refresh page and try again it gives me.

Comment: Please include the functional example in a snippet in the question (You can use the  icon which contains `<>` in the editor) rather than on an external site.

Comment: For me `console.log("rand "+ randomNum);` in your page outputs non-0 numbers

Comment: `Math.random()` generates a number between 0 and 1. `Math.floor()` will round down, so until your `arr.length-1` is greater than 10, you will always see 0. Not sure what you expect the range on your random number to be, but you probably want to do something like `Math.random() * 100`

Comment: @DBS the code doesn't end here so I have to post only the random number generating function

Comment: @Justinas is it just for me then? Can you recheck 2/3 and verify again plz, sorry for the trouble

Comment: The length of arr.length is 7 @peinearydevelopment